# Replace alphabets with spaces

Tags: netsuite

I want to print item.rate but only with having integer values in it.Currently it is printing the rate and also the currency in character.I want to hide the chars.

```
<td> ${item.rate} </td>
```

Comment: Could you provide some examples and show what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use Freemarker's `replace` function. See https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_replace for reference.

I'd recommend using a regular expression to find everything that's not a number. That should look something like:

```
${item.rate}?replace('\D', '', 'r')
```

Reference for Freemarker's regular expression syntax is here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html